# How do I get Facebook to return to my app after login if using phonegap plain on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a phonegap app that I use the Facebook plugin to implement single sign on.  I registered am a native iPhone app since the app is not run in the browser.  When I click on login I get an invalid URL error message.  I suspect my problem is either I need to specify a URL which I have tried using channel in init but I get a URL not allowed with this configuration.  The other problem may be that I need to register this application as a web app.  However using  phonegap the application does not have a url.  I don't know what to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I had similar problems. You should read the facebook sdk manual carefully

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [iOS URL scheme](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect#ios-url-scheme) section of the Plugin's readme?